# All checkins for a tag in svn

Tags: svn

How can I find out all checkins in to a Relase.
I need to fnid out what all changed between two tags. Each tag becomes a minor release.

I used the following cmd to find out the revisoin number for a tag

```
svn log <path/to/tag> -v --stop-on-copy
```

I got this from :
[SVN find revision of tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246988/svn-find-revision-of-tag)

e.g.

```
svn log <path/to/tag3.7.19> -v --stop-on-copy
```

and

```
svn log <path/to/tag3.7.18> -v --stop-on-copy
```

This gives me two revison numbers. 
Can I use this or something else to find out a list of all checkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your start and end revision numbers.

If you need a list of check-in messages between 2 revs, specify *revision range*:

```
svn log -r start-rev-no:end-rev-no
```

If you want a list of changed items per commit as well, include `--verbose` in above command:

```
svn log --verbose -r start-rev-no:end-rev-no
```