# How to check with svn if the trunk have just been tagged

Tags: bash, svn

I set up an automatic compilation process in shellscript, and I just want to figure if the trunk didn't received any commit from the last tagging... Is there a way to perform it with a *simple* svn command line, without read and compare the history, "scriptly" or manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVN a tag is neither an alias for a revision nor immutable. Instead it is just a copy! It is possible to modify the tag after it has been created. So the only way is to compare the revision numbers of the two paths. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246988/402322) question shows how to get them.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ceving, here's a nice sample to check if a project tree is up-to-date regarding tags.

Given that a project is set as the following :

```
rootdev/prj1/
rootdev/prj1/trunk
rootdev/prj1/tags
```

Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
tabs 30 # be fancy

function last-rev ()
{
    svn log "$1" -r HEAD:1 -l 1 -q | grep -ao '^r\S*'
}

find rootdev -ipath "*tags" |
while read tags
do
    module="$(dirname $tags)"
    modulename="$(basename $module)"
    lasttag="$(ls -1 $tags | tail -n 1)"
    lastrev=$(last-rev "$module")
    lasttagrev=$(last-rev "$tags/$lasttag")
    echo -ne "$modulename\t: $lasttag\t$lasttagrev/$lastrev "
    [[ "$lastrev" == "$lasttagrev" ]] && echo "[UPTODATE]" || echo "[OUTDATED]"
done
```

Output :

```
DateUtils                     : 1.0.0                       r116/r116 [UPTODATE]
ThisUtils                     : 1.0.0                       r116/r116 [UPTODATE]
SomeUtils                     : 1.2.1                       r125/r125 [UPTODATE]
ThatUtils                     : 1.0.1                       r101/r101 [UPTODATE]
NotUtils                      : 1.0.0                       r101/r128 [OUTDATED]
WhyUtils                      : 1.2.0                       r130/r130 [UPTODATE]
```